# Flutter get assets by wildcard suffix

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a folder of assets called `stickers`. The folder contains images (`.png`, `.jpeg`) and gifs (`.gif`). I want to show the user all his stickers.

My `stickers` folder:

[image]

My current code supports `png` files only:

```
children: List.generate(30, (index) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: Image(
                  image: AssetImage(
                    'assets/stickers/sticker_${index + 1}.png',
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
```

**How do I list assets, based on names, ignoring the file suffix?**

**Or how to support wildcard assets in flutter?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can copy the assets names with a mixed sort in a list like this :

```
const List assetslist = const [
  'sticker_1.png',
  'sticker_2.png'
  'sticker_3.jpeg'
  'sticker_4.png'
  'sticker_5.gif'
  'sticker_6.png'
];
```

then use it to generate an image for each of text:

```
  children: assetslist.map((e) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: Image(
        image: AssetImage(
          e,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }).toList(),
```

Comment: Well... it definitely will work, but I'm looking for much "clean" and simple solution. Also I don't want all the gifs be at the end or start, I want all types to be mixed.

Comment: I have another solution i will post it for you now

Comment: I must say @Afandi Yusuf commented a similar solution, but still you have updated your answer. For upcoming users, sofar this is the correct dart available answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can add assets by wildcard by adding this at the pubspec.yaml.

```
  assets:
    - assets/stickers/
```

But, for wildcard assets, you can't use hot reload if you update those assets inside that folder, you need completely stop the app and start again via android studio or vs code.

Comment: Hey @Afandi Yusuf thanks for replying. I have already added the images on pubspec. I can get all images. My problem is that I want to run on all images, while I don't know the suffix of them. In many languages you can just add a * at the suffix, but I think wildcard is not supported in dart (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Well, I think flutter doesn't have any function in listing loaded assets.
I think you may listing your assets through a JSON file, and load them by manipulating the model object based on that json.
Since the asset from pubspec is static, you can update that JSON file when updating files inside that folder.

Comment: Still.. complicated, But JSOn all stickers paths sounds best flexible solution so far. Thanks!